# How do you edit a vector using input?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am creating a video game store database and am having trouble with the function to edit inside the vector.  Ex. If I have mario kart inside the vector and say like its mispelled or prices changes etc I want to be able to go in and edit it. I am fairly new to c++ so criticize me if needed.

Here is what I have so far btw I am graving data from a file and writing back out to it.

heres my full code if u wanna try it out http://pastebin.com/Jp0qGXZB

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
char resp;
string gedit;
string name;
string new_name;
const string SPACES = "                            ";

fin.open("thegamestore.txt");
fout.open("thegamestore.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);

if (fout.fail())
{
    cout << "Error";
    exit(1);
}

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Error";
    exit(1);
}

do
{
    fin >> gname;
    gamename.push_back(gname);
    fin >> gconsole;
    console.push_back(gconsole);
    fin >> gstock;
    stock.push_back(gstock);
    fin >> gprice;
    price.push_back(gprice);
} while(!fin.eof());

for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = gamename.begin(); it != gamename.end(); ++it)
{
    sort(gamename.begin(), gamename.end());
    gamename.erase(unique(gamename.begin(), gamename.end()), gamename.end());
    cout << *it << endl;
    *it=gedit;
}

cout << "Which game would you like to edit?\n";
cin >> name;

if (name == gedit)
{
    cout << SPACES << "a:NAME\n";
    cout << SPACES << "b:CONSOLE\n";
    cout << SPACES << "c:STOCK\n";
    cout << SPACES << "d:PRICE\n";
    cin >> resp;

    if ('a'==resp)
    {
        cout << "Type in the new name\n";
        cin >> new_name;
        name=new_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless this is an assignment, I recommend you use a database.  Let the database manage the data, such as insert, *edit*, and searching.  A popular database is MySql and has document examples using C++.

Comment: Agree with @Thomas Matthews; I would consider doing this completely differently with a database.

Comment: this is an assignment im required to do this :( i gotta make this using STL

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different data structure for this, since you are trying to access items by name. `vector` (and arrays) can only be accessed by index. One that would work would be [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (especially since you want them to be unique).

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can make a map of `string` (`name`) to `vector<string>` with `[console, stock, price]`. Now you can access the console, stock, and price (and name).

So you initialize with a lot of `<>`s :)

```
map<string, vector<string>> games;
```

The first string is the name, then the vector is the console, stock, and price (all strings).

When reading from the file:

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    // We know it's 3 big. We could use a C array but why not use vector
    vector<string> details(3);
    for (int i=0; i<details.size(); ++i)
    {
        fin >> details[i];
    }
}
```

You should use a `while` loop rather than a `do...while` to check for eof at begging of file (0 byte file) when reading `fin`.

Your middle loop is odd and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve (sorting the list for every entry and then assigning an undefined game name?) However you can print every game name by looping the `map`. This is possible but not like you would expect from a vector: the order is not what you put in (they are sorted internally for speed).

```
for (auto i = games.begin(); i != games.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->first;
}
```

The map iterator (I used C++11 `auto` because it's typedef is *long*) points to a `pair` which contains `first` and `second`. `first` is your key (your game name). `second` is the other part (your console, stock, and price).

Now you can quickly access games by name. This is much more scalable than searching for a specific name.

```
auto game = games.find(name);
if ('a' == resp)
{
    if (game != games.end())
    {
        cout << "Type in the new name\n";
        cin >> game->first;
    }
}
else if (resp > 'a' && resp <= 'd')
{
    // Here we can access the other data.
    // To avoid writing so many conditionals we calculate the index.
    // 'b' - 'b' is zero: console. Etc.
    int index = resp - 'b';
    cout << game->second[index];
}
```

PS: Written quickly: this may be error-ridden.

Comment: I have my own file I created . I input the games from the add function.  This is an assignment for school. And the list has to be sorted according to the assignment, then again why am i sorting it  if i am editing and not viewing the list haha. and I have a question are arrays part of the STL? I was told it wasnt thats why i didnt go abouts using an array structure.

Comment: std::vector is from stl. Pointers (C-style arrays) are, obviously, core language.

Comment: Also: If it's for an assignment, I guess you can't do it the right way. But you can simply do `gamenames[index] = new_name;`